# How to compute a probability of a multiplication?

Tags: probability

Suppose I want to know P(a*(x>3)) and I know that P(x>3) is equal to 0.5 and "a" is a constant.
Is it correct to say that P(a*(x>3))=0.5? as "a" is a constant and it does not influence my probability.
Do you have any other suggestion on how I could solve that?

Comment: What does $P(a*(x>3))$ mean? Do you mean $P(a*x>3)$?

Comment: No I have P(a*x>a*3) so I though I could group together the "a"

Comment: You cannot do that. But $P(a*x>a*3)$ is $P(x>3)$ if $a >0$, it is $P(x<3)$ if $a <0$ and it is $0$ of $a=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you tell me where I can find some insight about that? (Properties, definition of probabilities..) for example, what appens if I decide to compute an expected value conditional of P(ax>a3)? Can i Just condition to P(x>3) if a is positive? I do not know where I can find some explaination to that

Comment: The only insight you need is if two statements are equivalent they have the same probability.